# Testing all the elements in collection fulfil predicate

Tags: junit, hamcrest

I need to test method which returns ordered `List` of some complex objects. Simplified example:

```
class MyObject {
    public String foo() { return someString; }
}
```

I want to test both: orderable of returned collection (since now I was using `org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains` and fulfiling predicate).

To sum up. I'm looking for such syntax:

```
@Test
public void shouldMatchPredicate() {
    List<MyObject> collection = testObject.generate();
    //collection = [myObject#x, myObject#y, myObject#z]
    assertThat(collection, somePredicate("x", "y", "z")
}
```

Default one, `contains` method is not working, since first argument is `Collection<MyObject>` and arguments in predicate are `String`s. I need some kind of bridge between it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Predicate` is a Guava object and Hamcrest does not depend on Guava it will not have a Matcher that will take a `Predicate`. Also, since Guava is not dependent on Hamcrest, they will not provide a Matcher either.

I suggest writing your own Matcher that takes a Predicate. This is relatively easy to do. Get the source code for `IsIterableContainingInOrder` and modify it to take a `Predicate`.

Another option would be to do the following:

```
assertThat(Iterables.all(myList, myPredicate), CoreMatchers.is(true));
```

This won't give you much documentation on a failure but it will pass/fail properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `MyObjectFactory` in `testObject.generate()`, avoiding the direct `new` statement.
`MyObjectFactory` would be a dependency of `testObject`.
Doing so, I would obtain 2 benefits:

1. A weaker coupling between `testObject` and `MyObject` (`testObject` would know `MyObject` only in terms of interface
2. The possibility to mock `MyObjectFactory` and, finally, the possibility to assert the 3 ordered calls: `MyObjectFactory.BuildNewWithValue("x")`, `MyObjectFactory.BuildNewWithValue("y")` and `MyObjectFactory.BuildNewWithValue("z")`

Your unit test would be an interaction test.

To assert the returned collection itself, I would write 3 asserts.

Comment: Data generation is out-of-scope this question. It is very simplified example - in my real scenario it uses 3rd party code and general - method can't be much modified. About assertions - yes, it will work, but I'm looking cleaner way (cleaner Hamcrest way?)